# Perl get array element from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, perl

I wanted to fetch array element and store in Perl variable. If I put `0` in replace of `?` in `$cur->{Type}[?]->{_id}` I'm able to get only one array element but I want all. below is my collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7fdb050cc3c23478005741"),
    "DBName" : "sample",
    "DBServerURL" : "mongodb://localhost:27017/",
    "Type" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b801dc963f8c81df83891bd")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b801dc963f8c81df83891be")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b801dc963f8c81df83891bf")
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b801dc963f8c81df83891c0")
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get `ObjectId` from all fields

```
$cursor = $CustColl->find(
    {DBName => "sample",DBServerURL => "mongodb://localhost:27017/"},{'_id' => 1, 'Type.$._id' => 1, 'DBServerURL' => 1, 'DBName' => 1}
);
while(my $cur = $cursor->next){
    my $cid = "$cur->{_id}" ;
    my $jid = "$cur->{Type}[?]->{_id}" ;
    my $url = "$cur->{DBServerURL}" ;
    my $name = "$cur->{DBName}" ;
    print "$cid : $jid : $url : $name\n" ;
}
```

I wanted an output like below:

```
5b7fdb050cc3c23478005741 : 5b801dc963f8c81df83891bd : mongodb://localhost:27017/ sample
5b7fdb050cc3c23478005741 : 5b801dc963f8c81df83891be : mongodb://localhost:27017/ sample
5b7fdb050cc3c23478005741 : 5b801dc963f8c81df83891bf : mongodb://localhost:27017/ sample
5b7fdb050cc3c23478005741 : 5b801dc963f8c81df83891c0 : mongodb://localhost:27017/ sample
```

Comment: What is the source of your data? In particular, what are the `ObjectId(...)` items? These make it invalid JSON, and there's not much you can do without sanitising it first.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. First, I fixed up your data to make it JSON but that's not a big deal:

```
my $json = q([{
    "_id" : "5b7fdb050cc3c23478005741",
    "DBName" : "sample",
    "DBServerURL" : "mongodb://localhost:27017/",
    "Type" : [
        {
            "_id" : "5b801dc963f8c81df83891bd"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "5b801dc963f8c81df83891be"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "5b801dc963f8c81df83891bf"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "5b801dc963f8c81df83891c0"
        }
    ]
} ]);

use JSON::XS;
my $perl = decode_json( $json );
```

That's a JSON array so you can go through it one element at a time. In Perl that shows up as an array reference Using the [postfix dereference](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) introduced in v5.20 makes this palatable (but not so hard without it):

```
while(my $cur = shift $perl->@*){   # or @$perl
    my $cid = $cur->{_id} ;
    my $url = $cur->{DBServerURL} ;
    my $name = $cur->{DBName} ;
    foreach my $hash ( $cur->{Type}->@* ) {  # or @{ $cur->{Type} }
        my $jid = $hash->{_id};
        print "$cid : $jid : $url : $name\n" ;
    }
}
```

The trick is that the `$jid` stuff is in another array and you want to go through those individually.  There's a `foreach` inside the `while` to do that. It runs once for each of those and outputs the lines.

Comment: *"I fixed up your data to make it JSON but that's not a big deal"* I would have thought it was a *very* big deal, depending on what `ObjectId(...)` means. I don't think you can just strip those out without confirming with the OP, and even if you do you should be writing code to do it instead of just starting with a fixed version of the input.

Comment: The data weren't the important thing. It's getting at all the elements from an array of hashes that's in question. Once anyone knows how to do that, they can adjust that for their situation. Furthermore, it's quite obvious that the data used in the OP code example isn't that data.